# JPA criteria query how to "given string" like column+%

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

Creating a query/ a Predicate where the content of a column (in my case a set of strings) begins with a given string is easy:

```
public static <E> Predicate stringBeginsWithAnyInSet(String match, SetAttribute<E, String> setAttribute,
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, Root<E> root) {
    SetJoin<E, String> setJoin = root.join(setAttribute);

    return criteriaBuilder.like(setJoin, match + "%");
}
```

but i need it the other way around the given string must begin with the value in the column - in my case with ate least one value.

The problem

```
criteriaBuilder.like( match + "%", setJoin);
```

is not compiling.

How to achieve the query and not changing the predicate signature - the given string is known and predicate should contain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

> given string must begin with the value in the column

So If I good understand You want sth like this
(Let me explain this on table `users` with column `email`)

```
select u.email as col_0_0_
from users u where 'given_email' like concat(u.email, '%');
```

When translate it into `JPA` `CriteriaQuery` we have:

```
criteriaBuilder.like(builder.literal("given_email"), builder.concat(user.get(User_.email), "%"))
```